# .NET MVC - QuickBooks OAuth2 API - How to set endpoints

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I can't figure out where or if I need to configure the API endpoints for QuickBooks OAuth2.

If I prepend the base URL for the code request, QuickBooks correctly returns to the redirect URL with a code.  After that, I don't know how to add the endpoint for the token exchange.

On the token exchange, I'm getting the exception:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: endpoint
```

Ultimately, I can't figure out how to set up the end points correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class QuickbooksController : Controller
{
    public static OAuth2Client oauthClient = new OAuth2Client(
        "REDACTED",
        "REDACTED",
        "https://localhost:302/QuickBooks/AccessToken/",
        "sandbox");

    // GET: Quickbooks
    public ActionResult Index(string connect, string msg)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(connect)) {

            //Prepare scopes
            List<OidcScopes> scopes = new List<OidcScopes>();
            scopes.Add(OidcScopes.Accounting);
            scopes.Add(OidcScopes.OpenId);

            string authorizeUrl =  oauthClient.GetAuthorizationURL(scopes);

            return Redirect("https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2" + authorizeUrl);
        }

        ViewBag.TokenFailed = false;
        ViewBag.ConfirmMessage = msg;
        return View(new QuickBooksViewModel(new App()));
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Accesstoken(string state, string code, string realmId)
    {
        try {
            TokenResponse tokenResponse = await oauthClient.GetBearerTokenAsync(code);

            if (tokenResponse.IsError) { 
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = "Error connecting to QuickBooks. Response: "  + tokenResponse.Raw });
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = "Connected to QuickBooks. Token: " + tokenResponse.AccessToken });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = "Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error: " + ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally:

Get the discovery document from the URL and assign it to the oauth client.  The discovery document is different for production, so you'll need to make it configurable.

Make sure to check for errors after the discovery document response.  I was missing a dll that wasn't throwing an error.

After this, all the end points should work, no need to prepend or assign anything.  Hope this saves someone else a few hours.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Connect()
{
    try { 
        DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration/");
        DiscoveryResponse doc = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();
        if (doc.IsError) {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = "Token Endpoint. Received error: " + doc.Error });
        }

        oauthClient.DiscoveryDoc = doc;

        //Prepare scopes
        List<OidcScopes> scopes = new List<OidcScopes>();
        scopes.Add(OidcScopes.Accounting);
        scopes.Add(OidcScopes.OpenId);
        //scopes.Add(OidcScopes.Email);

        string authorizeUrl = oauthClient.GetAuthorizationURL(scopes);

        return Redirect(authorizeUrl);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = "Token Endpoint. Error: " + ex.Message });
    }
}
```